# HTMX and Flask form can only Submit once

Tags: python, flask, htmx

I am working on a simple web app using HTMX and Flask, I have my `app.py` set up as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/submit', methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    print('submit clicked')
    input_text = request.form.get('inputText')
    return f'<p>You entered: {input_text}</p>'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I have my `templates/index.html` set up as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>HTMX Demo</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.10"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form hx-post="/submit" hx-target="#output" hx-swap="outerHTML">
      <div>
        <label for="inputText">Enter Text:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="inputText"
          name="inputText"
          placeholder="Type something..."
        />
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <div id="output">
      <!-- The result will be displayed here -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The goal is to be able to enter some text into the text box, hit the Submit button, and then have the text render in the output div.

However, this only works once. If I enter "test" and hit submit, it successfully renders the text in the output div. If I replace the form's text with "asasd" or something else and hit submit again, it does nothing. I don't even hit the `print('submit clicked')` line.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try adding `type="submit"` to your button, as see if that helps?

Answer (score 1):

`hx-swap` value should be `innerHTML`.

The second and all the following requests fail with `htmx:targetError`:

```
htmx:targetError htmx.org@1.9.10:1:26530
    b https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.10:1
    ce https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.10:1
    fe https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.10:1
    he https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.10:1
    Ht https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.10:1
    i https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.10:1
```

You may catch that in the console with [the debug extension](https://htmx.org/extensions/debug/) for `htmx`.

After the first request `<div id="output"></div>` is replaced with `<p>You entered: ...</p>` so the `#output` does no more exist in the document. Leaving it, replacing the only `innerHTML` will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying to use  the hx-boost attribute to the form, as it allows it to be rendered and answered multiple times. You can use it by adding this line to your code -

```
<form hx-post="/submit" hx-target="#output" hx-swap="outerHTML" hx-boost>
    <div>
    <label for="inputText">Enter Text:</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      id="inputText"
      name="inputText"
      placeholder="Type something..."
    />
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Please let me know if works out!

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work.